# How to parse xml coordinates onto google map

Tags: xml, json, parsing, google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing

What i have done so far is parsing data out of a JSON file using the instructions provided [By google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/data/importing_data). My question is what do i need to change for my codes so that i can parse data out of a xml file instead ?

Also i would like to add content to the info-window. Am i on the right track ?

My current code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
        </style>
        <script
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization">
        </script>


        <script>
         var map;
        function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.48939, 153.012772),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);

      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojsonp/2.5/week';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {

        var earthquake = results.features[i]; 
        var coords = earthquake.geometry.coordinates; 

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]); 

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          map: map,

        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<div>Hello! World</div>",
        maxWidth:100
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
            infowindow.open(this, marker);
        });

      }
    }


      </script>
      </head>

      <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
      </body>

      </html>
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to use XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`My question is what do i need to change for my codes so that i can parse data out of a xml file instead ?`

You don't need to change JSON to XML.  Anything you can do with data loaded from XML you can do with data loaded from JSON.

Comment: Thanks geocodezip. Just another quick question. I am trying to retrieve dynamic content information from a external source for my info-window. Base on what i had over here, how do i achieve that ? 

        `var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({`
        `content: "<div>Hello! World</div>",`
        `maxWidth:100`
        `});`

        `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function()` `{`
            `infowindow.open(this, marker);
        });`

Comment: Yes. Exactly like that.

Comment: View source in your browser (Ctrl-U in all the browsers I looked at)